# add_filter to youtube embeds?

Tags: filters, embed, youtube

hey guys,
when posting a youtube video link in the backend (in a post or a page) wordpress is automatically creating the embed code for me.

Is it possible to add a filter to that?
I'd love to change the width and height of all embedded videos to 100%?

e.g.

```
<object width="100%" height="100%">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/rBa5qp9sUOY?version=3">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/rBa5qp9sUOY?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="100%" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true">
</object>`
```

Any idea how to solve this?

edit: Or is it at least possible to add a classname to the object tag so I can use javascript to influence with and height of the embedded video?

update: Thank you I tried the following piece of code but it doesn't work?

```
add_filter('oembed_result','oembed_result', 10, 3);

function oembed_result($html, $url, $args) {

    // $args includes custom argument
    // modify $html as you need

    //return $html; 
}
```

if return $html is a comment no youtube video should appear right, however it does!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is a filter for Oembeds. Two (or even more) in fact: `oembed_result` will be called before it is put in the cache (so only once per external embed), and `embed_oembed_html` after the cache (so every time the item is displayed). If you only need to modify it once, `oembed_result` is probably your friend. The second parameter is the `$url`, so check whether it comes from Youtube before you do something.

Comment: thank you, however I can't seem to get it working! I updated my question so you can see what code I've tried. The filter doesn't seem to influence my youtube vids!

Comment: this is the solution: `add_filter('embed_oembed_html', 'add_video_embed_note', 10, 3);`

Comment: @mathiregister: If `oembed_result` does not work it is probably because that video is already in the cache. `embed_oembed_html` will always be executed - which is more flexible, but also a bigger burden on your server.

Comment: I am also trying to use the `oembed_result` filter and no matter what I seem to do, it doesn't appear to fire. I've also tried the `embed_oembed_html` filter and that doesn't seem to work either. Has anyone found a solution?